# Cannot find path '\LocalMachine\Personal' because it does not exist

Tags: powershell, iis, certificate-store

I am trying to access thumbprints of installed certificate on IIS 10 stores. I am using following command

```
Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\LocalMachine\Personal
```

but the above command giving me following error

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\LocalMachine\Personal
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\LocalMachine\Personal' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\LocalMachine\Personal
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\LocalMachine\Personal:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

However, the following command is returning with valid thumbprints

```
Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\LocalMachine\WebHosting
```

Interestingly, when I go to IIS>Server Certificate, I can see there are two store WebHosting and Personal.

[image]

I looked at [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability) and it states, which means there are WebHosting and Personal Store

> The Web Hosting store works like the Personal store, so all of the
> existing tools to import and export certificates work the same way.
> The key difference between Web Hosting store and Personal store is
> that Web Hosting store is designed to scale to higher numbers of
> certificates.

Can anyone suggest me why `Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\LocalMachine\Personal` is throwing an error?

Comment: Personal is actually `My`.

Comment: Personal store corresponds to the My Store. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename?view=netcore-3.1
Check the available certificate store name by using the below command
Get-ChildItem –path Cert:\localmachine\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Personal` is the logical store name in the MMC. In the PowerShell PSDrive, store name is `My`.

```
Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

I cannot speak for why this is different. However, you can run the following on a Windows systems to potentially spot other naming discrepancies:

```
certutil -enumstore
```

You can take the above command a step further and create your own mapping of naming mismatches:

```
(certutil -enumstore) -match '"[^"]+"' | Foreach-Object { 
    $PSStore,$MMCStore = ($_ -split '("[^"]+")').Trim(' ','"')[0,1]
    [pscustomobject]@{ 'PSStore' = $PSStore; 'MMCStore' = $MMCStore }
}
```